# Como ignorar uma exceção no php?

Tags: php

Estou consumindo um método de um sistema legado que gera varre alguns diretórios FTPs e procura arquivos. Porém, caso ele acesse um diretório que não tenha arquivos, ele gera uma exceção.
Existe alguma forma de eu conseguir utilizar esse método, porém, ignorar caso o mesmo gere essa exceção? (sem alterar o método original)

Comment: A primeira opção é arranjar esse código original. A segunda opção é criar mais código que verifica se o diretório tem arquivos e depois correr esse método caso haja arquivos... esconder problemas não é opção a meu ver.

Comment: Pode colocar o código dele?

Comment: Antes de acessar o FTP, verifica se tem arquivos no diretório...

Answer (score 5):

Se o objectivo é lidar com excepções, nada melhor do que `try / catch`:

```
try {
  chamarMetodo();
}
catch (Exception $e) {
  // lidar com erro
}
```

Para mais informação, ler: http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.exceptions.php